# How to paste an expression in the lme4 ranef() S4 class?

Tags: r, lme4, r-s4

Assuming I want to calculate random model effects with lme4.
Here is a sample model and the code to get random model effects from one variable by specifying it explicitely:

```
library(lme4)
model<-lmer(mpg ~ 1+ (1|wt) + (1|hp), data = mtcars,control=lmerControl(optCtrl=list(maxfun=20000)))
ranef(model)$wt
```

However, I would like to built this in a more flexible function, and for this I would need to paste the effects from which I want the random effects from a vector like this:

```
randomeffectlist<-NULL
effectlist<-c("wt","hp")
for (y in length (effectlist)){
  randomeffectlist[y]<-ranef(model)$effectlist[y]
}
```

After the $sign, I want to pass one after the other the elements of the factorlist to get for each effect the random effects in the randomeffectlist. In the current form, it does not work. I guess it is a problem of passing something after the $ symbol. How can this code be corrected?

Comment: I'm unclear what you are actually looking to create. Does the object `ranef(model)` not already contain what you need?

Comment: the problem is that after the $ sign, it does not take the value "wt" from the list, so there seems to be a problem of pasting with an S4 class...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use `$` when you compute the element to be extracted:

`ranef(model)$effectlist[y]` will literally look for a list element called `"effectlist[y]"`. Instead, you should use the double-square-bracket operator:

`ranef(model)[[effectlist[y]]]`.

From the help page for `[`:

"Both `[[` and `$` select a single element of the list. The main difference is that `$` does not allow computed indices, whereas `[[` does. `x$name` is equivalent to `x[["name", exact = FALSE]]`. Also, the partial matching behavior of `[[` can be controlled using the exact argument."

Comment: thanks, that was not really clear to me that the double-square-bracket operator can be used in calling the random effects from an lme4 model.

Comment: no problem --- this is not specific to `lme4` or `ranef`, in general you can't use `$` when you have to compute the part that comes after the `$`. See the help page on `[` for more details. Will update the answer with that info.